# How to host static website on AWS EC2 with ubuntu and nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I need to host a website on AWS EC2 micro with Ubuntu and NGINX.
So I get free domain name with dot.tk and mapped ElasticIP of my server with it (used dig utility to check if it pointed to my ip).
Then I changed nginx.conf on server and added these standard rows into http section:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.ml;
    root /data/www;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

But if I write my address in browser it does not show me something.

What I need to do else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow port 80 in your security groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to host a static web site on AWS, EC2 is not the right service to use. You can do so much more cheaply (and more scalably) by simply enabling the built-in Static Website Hosting feature of an S3 bucket.

Alastair Coote, the author of the famous [Is my Twitter password secure?](http://www.ismytwitterpasswordsecure.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) site (an educational site about phishing scams) wrote a nice article about his experience serving more than 100K users for USD $0.32: [How I served 100k users without breaking the server- or a dollar bill.](http://blogging.alastair.is/how-i-served-100k-users-without-crashing-and-only-spent-0-32/)

Comment: Actually I don't like to host only static website. I started with it because I noob in DevOps and I need to get some knowledge to do more useful things. I choose AWS EC2 because it has free program, and thats what I need right now. Anyway, thank you for your advice!